# Doctrine 2 - Access level problems when using Class Table Inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implent the [Class Table Inheritance](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance) Doctrine 2 offers in my Symfony 2 project.
Let's say a have a **Pizza** class, **Burito** class and a **MacAndCheese** class which all inherit from a ***Food*** class.

The ***Food*** class has the following settings:

```
<?php

namespace Kitchen;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="food")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="dish", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"pizza" = "Pizza", "burito" = "Burito", "mac" => "MacAndCheese"})
 */
class Food {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

And the inherited classes have these settings (**Pizza** for example):

```
<?php

namespace Kitchen;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="food_pizza")
 */
class Pizza extends Food {
```

When running *doctrine:schema:update --force* from the Symfony 2 app/console I get an error about the access level of *$id* in the children of ***Food*** (**Pizza** for example), stating it must be protected or weaker. I haven't declared *$id* anywhere in the **Pizza**, since I reckoned it would be inherited from ***Food***.

So I tried to declare *$id*, but that gives me an error, cause I can't redeclare $id.
I figure I need some kind of reference to $id from ***Food*** in **Pizza**, but the Doctrine 2 documentation didn't really give me a clear answer on what this would look like.

Hopefully you understand what I mean and can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently I should have investigated the code generated by *doctrine:generate:entities* a bit more. When I started my IDE this morning and seeing the code again, I noticed that it had 'copied' all of the inherited fields (like *$id* in ***Food***, in the example above) to the children (**Pizza**, in the example above).

For some reason it decided to make these fields *private*. I manually changed the access level to *protected* in all of the classes and I tried to run *doctrine:schema:update --force* again: it worked!

So, as in many cases, the solution was a good night's rest! ;)

*If someone comes up with a better solution and / or explanation for this problem, please do post it. I'd be more than happy to change the accepted answer.*

Comment: Are you saying your IDE was the one changing the access level on your fields? That's kind of scary. What IDE do you use so I can keep an eye out for that happening?

Comment: @cantera25 It wasn't the IDE, it was the Symfony 2 doctrine:generate:entities command that did that.

Comment: @ArnoMoonen I think it's all right, because the childs of Food has access only to `protected` or `public` properties of parent. Thats why you need to define `protected` instead `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Something to keep in mind:

> Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.  You cannot generate
>   entities in an inheritance hierachy currently (beta) As a workaround
>   while generating methods for new entities, I moved away from project
>   inheritated entities and after generating I moved them back.

[source](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-790?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I can tell this really is all about generating entities and I just want to generate my database (perhaps these methods are related internally in Doctrine 2 though, I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

May be you should define the @ORM\DiscriminatorMap in a such way:

```
/**
 *
 ..
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"food" = "Food", "pizza" = "Pizza", "burito" = "Burito", "mac" => "MacAndCheese"})
 */
```

If you compare your code with the example from Doctrine site, you will see that they added parent entity to the DiscriminatorMap.